# PHP/MongoDB: How to sort documents depending if userId(String) exist in list of ids?

Tags: php, android, regex, mongodb, sorting

Let's say I have the following documents in a collection called "posts":

```
{  
   "_id":ObjectId("56454e4a32d6b633753e455b"),
   "comment":"Give it 6 - 8 years and this duo will",
   "userid":"5643ad3b3185a",
},
{  
   "_id":ObjectId("22224e4a32d6b633753e455b"),
   "comment":"Give it 6 - 8 years and this duo will",
   "userid":"2222ad3b3185a",
},
{  
   "_id":ObjectId("11114e4a32d6b633753e455b"),
   "comment":"Give it 6 - 8 years and this duo will",
   "userid":"1111ad3b3185a",
}
```

I wish to sort this three documents depending if the "userid" field exist in a list of ids. for example.

```
$listIds=[8888883b3185a,999999d3b3185a, 2222ad3b3185a]

.sort("_id":-1, **array("userid":array("$in":$listIds))**)
```

I know the second part of the sort is wrong but how can I accomplish the goal of what I am trying to do in that sort, which is sorting the documents depending if userid belongs to a list of ids?

Desired output after sort:

```
{  
   "_id":ObjectId("22224e4a32d6b633753e455b"),
   "comment":"Give it 6 - 8 years and this duo will",
   "userid":"2222ad3b3185a",
},
{  
   "_id":ObjectId("56454e4a32d6b633753e455b"),
   "comment":"Give it 6 - 8 years and this duo will",
   "userid":"5643ad3b3185a",
},
{  
   "_id":ObjectId("11114e4a32d6b633753e455b"),
   "comment":"Give it 6 - 8 years and this duo will",
   "userid":"1111ad3b3185a",
}
```

Document with "userid":"2222ad3b3185a" will be first because the id exist in the list of ids.

Comment: So should it just be a sort where all existing IDs appear nonexisting ones, or should it also be sorted by the ID too? You haven't made that part clear.

Comment: sorry about that. YES all documents should appear after sorting them BUT the ids that exist in the list should be on top.